# How to create a "debug" enabled version of a signed native installer?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

By adding an empty file called "debug" to the META-INF/AIR folder in an AIR application, it is possible to do all sorts of great things, including the ability to call getStackTrace() on an error event, which could be extremely useful in diagnosing uncaughtErrorEvents.  However, try as I may, I can't figure out how to create a signed native installer with the empty "debug" file in this folder.

I have tried including META-INF/AIR/debug in my src directory.  When I export the release version and check "keep bin-release-temp folder", the "debug" file is present; however, it's not included in the installer.

I've also tried adding "-debug=true" as an additional compiler argument, but this seems to have no effect.

I've seen some instructions on how to edit and re-sign an ipa.  I wonder if there  might be a way to do the same thing with my native installer.  I think it might involve unzipping it, adding the "debug" folder to META-INF/AIR, and then zipping it back up and signing it.  Somehow I think it would be more complicated than this.

Comment: I am trying to produce a Signed Native Installer that I can easily distribute as an update to approximately 100 installs.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the empty file named "debug" to show up in the META-INF/AIR folder.

Comment: here is a clarification of how this "debug" file works:  [link](http://backroom.bostonproductions.com/?p=902).

Answer (score 0):

For your task I usually use a very powerful debugger called Monster debugger (http://www.demonsterdebugger.com)

You will need to only include their SWC to the source and initialize the debugger somewhere in the beginning of your program. After that you'll have many advanced features available:

- tracing objects
- pausing program state
- changing variables on run-time

and many more.

Check it out, there's a very nice tutorial for it that looks and feels like a game.

Oh, yeah, and it's free too!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `conditional compilation`. It's great instrument for debugging purposes.

`define=NAMESPACE::variable,value`

> Defines a global constant. The value is evaluated at compile time and exists as a constant within the application. A common use of inline constants is to set values that are used to include or exclude blocks of code, such as debugging or instrumentation code. This is known as conditional compilation.

Example:

```
-define=CONFIG::DEBUG,true

//In code
CONFIG::DEBUG{
    //your code with debugging, logging, whatever
}
```

If you don't want to work with `conditinal compilation` and you need some flag in your air application, you could compile your air application with file (xml file is great choice, because there is E4X), in your case, let's call it settings file.

*change information in brackets, and remove brackets*

```
"[Path to the FlexSDK]\bin\adt" -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "[Path to the Air certificate]\myCert.p12" -storepass [Certificate password] "[Path to result]\myApp.air" "[path to the app descriptor]\my-app.xml" -C "[Path to your stuff]" myApp.swf settings.xml
```

Organise `settings.xml` how you want it, set there useful flags, load it in runtime.

```
private function getSettings():XML{
    var fileToCreate : File = File.applicationDirectory;
    var stream : FileStream = new FileStream();
    var fileData : String;

    fileToCreate = fileToCreate.resolvePath("settings.xml");
    stream.open(fileToCreate, FileMode.READ);
    fileData = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);

    return new XML(fileData);
}
```